# Bluetooth LE unexpected disconnect on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

My iOS app connects as Central to a BLE peripheral and receives data updates at sub-second intervals. The connection logic works as expected, except for unexpected disconnects on the iPhone 6, usually after 30-90 seconds. iOS provides only this error information:

```
didDisconnectPeripheral: Peripheral with UUID = NNNN disconnected, error = Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=6 "The connection has timed out unexpectedly." UserInfo=NNN {NSLocalizedDescription=The connection has timed out unexpectedly.}
```

Online investigation indicates this may be due to wireless signal interference, so I'm looking for specifics that would allow mitigating the interference. For example:

- disconnect occurs on iPhone 6 (Verizon), but not iPhone 4S (gsm). Both phones running iOS 8.1.3
- disconnect occurs even when iPhone 6 is within 12 inches of the peripheral,
- disconnect occurs even with nearby macbook wi-fi turned off
- environment has other wi-fi and RF sources that can't be turned off

Is the iPhone 6, the Verizon version, or some larger set of iOS devices more susceptible to BLE interference?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue. It only happens on iPhone 6 and IPhone 6+. We've test on iPhone 4 - iPhone 5S on iOS version iOS 7 - iOS 8 and not seeing anything similar. Not sure on the carriers. Also, I only see this when actually reading from a characteristic. If I simple connect to the BLE module the connection will maintain. If I begin writing to a characteristic on 1 - 1.5 second intervals the connection will disconnect within 30 - 90 seconds.

Comment: There is some discussion of this on the Apple dev forums at https://devforums.apple.com/thread/256525?tstart=30

Comment: thinking this may have been due to low battery on the peripheral device. Haven't been able to reproduce recently.

Comment: This has stopped happening as frequently for us to, but per my previous comment we did slow down the interval at which we were reading. I could switch that back and see if I'm still seeing the issue.